# How to turn entire keras model into theano function

Tags: python, theano, keras

I want to turn my keras model into a theano function so that I can compute the gradients on the inputs.  I thought this might be cool for visualizing the network.  I want to use these gradients to enhance features in the original image based on what the neural network thinks they are.  I do not understand what I am doing wrong with the following code.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer((3, H, W)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.03))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu', name = 'dense'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(C, activation = 'softmax', W_regularizer = l2()))
...
f = theano.function([model.input], model.output)
```

I get the following exception.

```
theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: A variable that is an input to the graph was neither provided as an input to the function nor given a value. A chain of variables leading from this input to an output is [keras_learning_phase, DimShuffle{x,x}.0, Elemwise{switch,no_inplace}.0, dot.0, Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, dot.0, Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Softmax.0]. This chain may not be unique
Backtrace when the variable is created:
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 13, in <module>
    _LEARNING_PHASE = T.scalar(dtype='uint8', name='keras_learning_phase')  # 0 = test, 1 = train
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the [FAQ](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer), try:

```
from keras import backend as K
get_last_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                   [model.layers[-1].output])
```

For the most recent version of Keras (1.0), use

```
from keras import backend as K
get_last_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                   [model.layers[-1].get_output(train=False)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For "old" keras(0.3.x for example):

I don't use this version but examples like [this one](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/41#issuecomment-91078316) should work.

For "new" keras(1.0+):

Since you use `Dropout` layer, you will need to add another input `K.learning_phase()` and give it the value 0 (0 for testing, 1 for training.)

code:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[-1].output])
```

Reference: [keras FAQ](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)