# Keras model to Theano function

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to convert a trained model (code given below) to a theano function. But I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'output'`.

The code for my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The code I am using to convert the Keras model to a theano function by following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221621/how-to-turn-entire-keras-model-into-theano-function):

```
 from keras import backend as K
    get_last_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                       [model.layers[-1].output])
    y=f(patches)
```

Can anyone please tell me what to do?

Comment: Hey - please specify the version of Keras which you use. Since version 1.0 there were a lot of changes in implementation.

Comment: I am using the latest version of keras and Theano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `model.layers[-1].get_output(train=False)`.  The [original Keras tutorial](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) may be outdated.

Comment: Now getting another error. In thce second line i,e, y=f(patches). The error says AssertionError :assert type(inputs) in {list, tuple}.

Comment: @AvijitDasgupta How about `y=f([patches])`?

Comment: Yes yes! I have already changed it to y=f([patches]).  Let me try and I will let you know :)

Comment: How to specify the batch size? variable patches is too big to fit in my GPU memory. :/

Comment: You'll have to manually take care of the batch construction, by calling your function inside a for loop